# Bug in shell script for printing the tree-like structure of the curent diretcory

Tags: scripting, recursive

I have wrote the following script:

```
  #!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    read current_dir
else
    current_dir=$1
fi

function print_tree_representation ()
{
    for file in `ls -A $1`
    do
        local times_p=$2
        while [ $times_p -gt 0 ]
        do
            echo -n "----"
            times_p=$(( $times_p - 1 ))
        done
        echo $file

        if test -d $file
        then
            local new_path=$1/$file
            local new_depth=$(( $2 + 1 ))

            print_tree_representation $new_path $new_depth        
        fi
    done
}

print_tree_representation $current_dir 0
```

for printing the tree-like structure of the directory passed as argument. However, it doesn't go beyond the second level of depth. I can't figgure out what is wrong.

Comment: Did you know that there is a `tree` command ?  Have you checked it?

Comment: @val0x00ff Do I need to say that this is a homework problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
if test -d $file
```

The `$file` you have extracted from `ls -A` doesn't contain the full path.  You can fix it by replacing that line with

```
if test -d "$1/$file"
```

There's another bug, which is that it'll break all over the place if a filename has spaces in it.  Put filenames in quotes.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually a pretty stupid mistake, that I did.